# Efficient retrieval of last and second to last element of ArrayStack in Scala?

Tags: scala, stack

I am using a mutable `ArrayStack` in Scala but do not know how to access the last element (and second to last element) efficiently (constant time) without popping the items from the stack. Is it possible to access the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stack(4)    // returns 5th element
stack.last  // returns last element
```

Those operations are constant time.

Comment: I also found stack.apply(). Is this the same thing?

Comment: Yes it is. ``stack(4)`` actually calls ``stack.apply(4)``

Answer (score 0):

`stack(4)` returns 5th element in constant time

As for the last element - the answer depends on which version you're using. Scala 2.11.7 was still running `stack.last` on linear time as it was using `TraversableLike` implementation:

```
def last: A = {
    var lst = head
        for (x <- this)
            lst = x
        lst
}
```

This was [fixed](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9507) in version 2.12.0-M4 using the `IndexedSeqOptimized` trait.
Therefor to my understanding - if you're using an older version of Scala (which was the case when the question was posted) you should use `stack(stack.size - 1)` which returns last element in constant time.